# How can I create a Snippet in Slack from a webhook

Tags: webhooks, slack-api

Is it possible to post a message in Slack from a webhook with a [Snippet](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/204145658-Create-a-snippet)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only post messages incl. attachments with webhook.

If you want to post a snippet, you need to use the API method [`files.upload`](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload). Snippets are automatically created based on the specified or detected `filetype`.